# Create subsite using template

Tags: sub-site

How can I create a sub site using my own template? I have activated template in solution list. But  can't choose this template while creating new sub site.

Comment: Are you using publishing site?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Site-Settings -> Look and Feel -> Page Layouts and Site Templates.

Make sure the template is listed under "allowed templates".